# PrimeNG : Display issue with Table - State

Tags: angular, dialog, primeng

I am developing with Angular 7 and PrimeNG. I have put a PrimeNG table (type: [state](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/state)) in a [PrimeNG Dynamic Dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dynamicdialog). However, the data table doesn't take the whole width of the dialog.
[image]

```
<p-table #dt1 [columns]="cols" [value]="myData" [paginator]="true" [rows]="5" dataKey="ID_Data"
selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedRow" [resizableColumns]="true" [reorderableColumns]="true">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pSortableColumn="col.field" pResizableColumn pReorderableColumn> 
            {{col.header}}
            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field" class="ui-fluid">
            <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt1.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)" [value]="dt1.filters[col.field]?.value">
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <span class="ui-column-title">{{col.header}}</span> {{rowData[col.field]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

```
showTable() {
   const ref = this.dialogService.open(PopUpTableComponent, {
      header: 'Data Table',
      width: '70%',
      contentStyle: {'max-height': '350px', 'overflow': 'auto'}
   });

   ref.onClose.subscribe();
```

}

I don't have any ideas of why there are issues as the paginator is on the whole width of the dialog.

Comment: have you tried to add a css class to modify the width of the table ? You can also try to add width on a column

Comment: @matirmv I tried but it is possible I haven't used the right class. I am still testing different solutions. I'll investigate manually adding width to columns.

Comment: @matirmv Since I am using State PrimeNG table, I can resize the columns' width which is useful for me as some of my columns are needed to be resized to read the data. By adding fixed width, the resizeable function doesn't work anymore. Edit: What bothers me is PrimeNG does say that the table width is automatically 100%

Comment: try adding a contentStyle css property like so : {
      header: 'Data Table',
      width: '70%',
      contentStyle: {'max-height': '350px', 'overflow': 'auto',width:'100%'}
   }

Comment: @matirmv It doesn't work. I think it is within p-table since the paginator does take 100% width. Only the table doesn't.

Comment: try the parameter columnResizeMode="expand" on the p-table component

Comment: @matirmv Still doesn't work... (Thanks for helping by the way)